# Winjs, error reading file with FileIO.readTextAsync

Tags: unicode, windows-8, winjs, windows-8.1

I am reading a .json file from disk using `Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync`.
All is fine until I put some non english letters in the file, like Æ Å Ø

The error I get is (rough translation from Danish language):
WinRT: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page.

any idea how to read those chars in WinJs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

when I created the file manually with notepad I set it to type ANSII instead of utf8. 
I reopened the file -> save as and the changed the type and overwrote it.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to solve this by changing the encoding from the default (`Utf8`) to `Utf16`. The [`readTextAsync` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh701485) accepts a second parameter which is a [UnicodeEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.unicodeencoding) flag:

```
Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync(
    file,
    Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.utf16LE
).done( ... );
```

Or if you need to, you can use `utf16BE` flag (see link above).

Comment: thanks I tried it but now I get Japanese letters back from my .json file

Comment: Weird... glad you found the solution though!